# Flutter : How to color Sizedbox (without using container)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

**1. Explanation**

I want to change full color of 'SizedBox' to see the location and scope of 'SizedBox'. I wonder is there any way to change SizedBox's color without filling it with Container or Decoration box. If not, I want to know how to fill SizedBox with decoration box.

**2. Code**

Here is a code that I tried.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home : Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title : const Text('this is title'),
        ),
        body : const SizedBox(
          width : 200,
          child: DecoratedBox(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color : Colors.red,
              ),
          ),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: (
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: const [
              Icon(Icons.favorite),
              Icon(Icons.home),
              Icon(Icons.settings)
            ],
          )
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**3. Result **

Here is what I got from the code.

[image: result of the code above]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try [ColoredBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ColoredBox-class.html) widget

```
SizedBox(
  width : 200,
  height: 20,
  child: ColoredBox(color: Colors.amber),
),
```

Answer (score 6):

You can wrap your `SizedBox` with `ColoredBox`

```dart
ColoredBox(
  color: Colors.cyanAccent,
  child: SizedBox(
      width: 200,
      height: 100,),
),
```

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to decorate the `SizedBox` to see the location and scope of the `Widget` just for debugging purposes, we can enable the `debugPaintSizeEnabled` just by pressing `p` on the CLI upon launching the `flutter run` command.

Otherwise, using a `Container` with explicit size parameters it's mostly the same as using `SizedBox`, and it would allow you to use have a background color or border decoration.

Another option would be to use a `ColoredBox` as the child of the `SizedBox`, or vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for introducing the concept of 'debugPaintSizeEnabled'. Though this was not the solution of changing color of SizedBox, it really helped me to check the scope of the components of widgets. Also, other solutions you gave me was really helpful too. Thanks again for answering my question, and have a nice day!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you'd use it but you could have the child of the SizedBox be a container with the color you want. The container will stretch to the sizes provided

```
SizedBox(
        height: 10,
        width: 30,
        child: Container(color: Colors.red), 
     ),
```

Also you could use the widget inspector provided by flutter:

[https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/devtools/inspector#:~:text=The%20Flutter%20widget%20inspector%20is,%2C%20rows%2C%20and%20columns](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/devtools/inspector#:%7E:text=The%20Flutter%20widget%20inspector%20is,%2C%20rows%2C%20and%20columns)).